# D3 - Getting text on the top of rectangles in Vertical Bar chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg, bar-chart

I am making a vertical bar chart with D3 successfully. I further want the value of frequency to lie on the top of each rectangle. I am able to get the complete structure and rectangles. But, I cannot see my values residing on top of the bars. Can someone help out?

**SNIPPET:**

```
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.12/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>

</head> 

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

    <svg></svg>

    <script>

        //module declaration 
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

        //Controller declaration
        app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

            $scope.svgWidth = 800;//svg Width
            $scope.svgHeight = 500;//svg Height 

            //Data in proper format 
            var data = [
                  {"letter": "A","frequency": "5.01"},
                  {"letter": "B","frequency": "7.80"},
                  {"letter": "C","frequency": "15.35"},
                  {"letter": "D","frequency": "22.70"},
                  {"letter": "E","frequency": "34.25"},
                  {"letter": "F","frequency": "10.21"},
                  {"letter": "G","frequency": "7.68"},
            ];

                //removing prior svg elements ie clean up svg 
                d3.select('svg').selectAll("*").remove();

                //resetting svg height and width in current svg 
                d3.select("svg").attr("width", $scope.svgWidth).attr("height", $scope.svgHeight);

                //Setting up of our svg with proper calculations 
                var svg = d3.select("svg");
                var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
                var width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
                var height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                //Plotting our base area in svg in which chart will be shown 
                var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                //X and Y scaling 
                var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.4);
                var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

                x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
                y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.frequency; })]);

                //Final Plotting 

                //for x axis 
                g.append("g")
                    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

                //for y axis 
                g.append("g")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
                    .append("text").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)").attr("text-anchor", "end");

                  //for rectangles 
                  g.selectAll(".bar")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "bar")
                    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
                    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

               g
                .selectAll(".bar")
                .append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".75em")
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d) { return y(d.frequency); });


        });

    </script> 

</body> 

</html>
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

**DOM:**

[image]

As, can be seen my text is added in dom per each rectangle, but cannot be seen. Pls help them being seen on top of rectangles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is simple: you **cannot** append a `text` element inside a `rect` element.

The `text` element will show up when you inspect the DOM, but this doesn't mean that it works, and no text will be actually painted in the SVG.

So, it should be:

```
 g.selectAll(".text")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".75em")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.frequency; });
```

Note that I changed

```
.text(function(d) { return y(d.frequency); });
```

which makes no sense, to:

```
.text(function(d) { return d.frequency; });
```

Here is a demo with your code:

```js
var data = [{
    "letter": "A",
    "frequency": "5.01"
}, {
    "letter": "B",
    "frequency": "7.80"
}, {
    "letter": "C",
    "frequency": "15.35"
}, {
    "letter": "D",
    "frequency": "22.70"
}, {
    "letter": "E",
    "frequency": "34.25"
}, {
    "letter": "F",
    "frequency": "10.21"
}, {
    "letter": "G",
    "frequency": "7.68"
}, ];


//Setting up of our svg with proper calculations 
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg").attr("width", 500).attr("height", 300);
var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 40
};
var width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//Plotting our base area in svg in which chart will be shown 
var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//X and Y scaling 
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.4);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.letter;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return +d.frequency;
})]);

//Final Plotting 

//for x axis 
g.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

//for y axis 
g.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)").attr("text-anchor", "end");

//for rectangles 
g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.letter);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.frequency);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.frequency);
    });

g.selectAll(".text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.frequency) - 16;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.letter) + x.bandwidth() / 2;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.frequency;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its working nicely. One more thing how can we rotate the text as (-90)deg in this example ?

Answer (score 1):

The text element should not be inside the rect element. Just append them to your g element instead.